# Get Knowledge Articles for custom lightning component

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, knowledge, sosl

I am trying to build a lightning component that will be used as a help landing page for one of our products. So I will be filtering the data category from apex and further filters by search terms using SOSL. Here is what I have so far but I am not getting any results in the component.

.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes" controller="GetHBArticles">
    <aura:attribute name="articles" type="SObject[]"/>

    <ui:button label="Get Articles" press="{!c.getArts}"/>
    <aura:iteration var="articles" items="{!v.articles}">
        <p>{!articles.Id} : {!articles.Title} : {!articles.ArticleType}</p>
    </aura:iteration>

</aura:component>
```

lightning controller

```
({
    getOpps: function(cmp){
        var action = cmp.get("c.getArts");
        action.setCallback(this, function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                cmp.set("v.articles", response.getReturnValue());
            }
        });
     $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

apex controller

```
public with sharing class GetHBArticles {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static List<List<SObject>> getArticlesList(){
        List<List<SObject>> articles = [FIND :searchVar RETURNING KnowledgeArticleVersion
                                                     (Id, Title, ArticleType WHERE PublishStatus='online' AND Language = 'en_US' AND ArticleType IN ('Troubleshooting__kav', 'How_To__kav', 'FAQ__kav'))
                                                     WITH DATA CATEGORY Topics__c AT 'DataCategoryName];
        return articles;
    }



}
```

Here is the error I see in the Chrome dev console when I click the button. 
[image: Browser Debug]

Also, I received a suggestion to map the id's of articles and build a wrapper class to traverse the KnowledgeArticleVersion object to KnowledgeArticle in order to sort the results by CaseAssociationCount. I would love to hear from anyone that has any examples of how I can do this. I have been reading up on it but I am spending a bit more time on it then I had hoped.

As always any help from this awesome group is greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is searchVar in your apex controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things here:
1. the button "press" action is looking for the controller method `getArts` but your controller's method is named `getOpps`
2. In your controller method, the method name you should be calling is the name of the Apex method, i.e.:
`var action = cmp.get("c. getArticlesList");`

This should give you a start at least.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you this worked. I can see my articles coming through in dev console.